# Unable to trigger error callback in jQuery AJAX using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to test the error callback using the below scenarios :

1. Change my url : "telemetry.php" to url : "asdasfjgafas.php"
2. Have `<?php header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); exit() >` inside telemetry.php

But, I don't get alert() of the error callback even after trying 1. and 2. separately!

My .js content making AJAX request using jQuery :

```
$.ajax({

    url     :   "telemetry.php",
    data    :   ({
                    DshBrdName  : strFullDashBoardName,
                    DshBrdID    : currentDashboard, 
                    r           : Math.random()
                }),
    success :   function(data, textStatus, jQxhr){
                    alert(textStatus); 
                },
    error   :   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
    type    :   "POST"
});
```

P.S : I am able to get success alert when I have valid url and valid php code!

Answer (score 1):

I can see a typo in your error block:

```
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(testStatus); // should be textStatus?
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
```

**EDIT**

From the js, point of view, everything seems ok, as your snippet below (I replaced the undefined variables with string) alerts the error (since this php script obviously isn't found). You may want to give more detail about what goes on at the server side...

```js
$.ajax({

    url     :   "telemetry.php",
    data    :   ({
                    DshBrdName  : 'strFullDashBoardName',
                    DshBrdID    : 'currentDashboard', 
                    r           : Math.random()
                }),
    success :   function(data, textStatus, jQxhr){
                    alert(textStatus); 
                },
    error   :   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
    type    :   "POST"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes you probably have error in console that says that `testStatus` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry guys.. I was manually typing those alerts in the stackoverflow page instead of copying from my php file... This is not a typo issue! In the real code, it is indeed alert(textStatus)

Comment: Running your script here gets the alert, so the problem may not be with javascript.